# difference em0, em1, bge0 - pfsense

Tags: networking, openvpn, pfsense

While assign interface in pfsense I found  three interfaces **em0, em1, bge0**. I assigned bge0 for WAN and em1 for LAN. it worked. but honestly I don't know what is the exact difference between these three.

**is either or case?** or **each one have any purpose?**

can anyone point the difference or use case of em0, em1, bge0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In BSD, network interfaces are named after which driver they use. So in your case, emX = Intel, and bgeX = Broadcom.

Any of your interfaces can be used for any purpose within pfSense. It's just up to you to examine the performance characteristics of each and decide accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration file on pfSense 2.3 has em0 assigned as WAN, and em1 assigned as LAN. If the target hardware has em0 and em1, then the assignment prompt is skipped and the install will proceed as usual.